# Best way to update a Web Service Call done in PHP after the page has loaded

Tags: javascript, php, rest, api

I have a webpage that uses PHP to make a REST API call and returns an JSON array used later in the page.  This php is meant to run on loading (yes, I understand php is ran server side), but it performs the API default request automatically upon loading the page.

I have an input group that is meant to change the query parameters of the API request which in turn updates the array that is being manipulated later.

I would assume that updating query parameters on the fly is a fairly common thing to be done - but the only way I can think to do it in my scenario is by calling my php to do it with the new parameters.

**This brings up 2 problems: *1* If I put the API call php code within a function, and try to call it with some ajax, it doesn't execute the default query on load. *2* If the api call is not in a function, I don't know how to call it again when I have updated parameters from my input group.**

### The API call:

```
    <?php

    $include = '';
    $exclude = '';

    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/dev30.json";
        $requestMethod = "GET";
        if (isset($_GET['topic']))  {$user = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/", '', $_GET['topic']);}  else {$user  = "@avaya";}
        //if (isset($_GET['count']) && is_numeric($_GET['count'])) {$count = $_GET['count'];} else {$count = 6;}


        $getfield = "?query=$user+$include+$exclude";


        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
        ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
        ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
        if(array_key_exists("errors", $string)) {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}


        $id_array = array();

        //Foreach loop to create divs

        foreach ($string['results'] as $tweets)
        {


          $id_array[] = $tweets['id_str'];


        }
    ?>
```

`$id_array` is used later in javascript as it is set to 
        `var jsarray = <?php echo json_encode($id_array); ?>;`

### Code for my input group to get new parameters:

```
                    <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-prepend"><span class="input-group-text">Exclude</span></div><input id="input-exclude" class="form-control" type="text">
                <div class="input-group-append"><button onclick="getExclude()" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Go</button></div>
                <script>
                function getExclude()
                {
                  var toExclude = document.getElementById('input-exclude').value;
                  console.log("getExclude() has been called");
                  console.log("You requested to exclude: " + toExclude);

                  excludeString = excludeString + "&"

                  //excluded =
                }

                <?php
                  if(isset($_COOKIE['include']))
                  {
                    $include = $_COOKIE['include'];
                  }
                ?>

                </script>
            </div>
```

This is just for the include portion of the problem - exclude is identical, just different on the API side so I left it out.

At this point I would like re-run the php bit with the updated value for `$include`. As mentioned earlier - I have tried put all of that php code in a function, like this:

```
                           function callTwitter(){
        $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/dev30.json";
        $requestMethod = "GET";
        if (isset($_GET['topic']))  {$user = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/", '', $_GET['topic']);}  else {$user  = "@avaya";}
        //if (isset($_GET['count']) && is_numeric($_GET['count'])) {$count = $_GET['count'];} else {$count = 6;}


        $getfield = "?query=$user+$include+$exclude";


        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
        ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
        ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
        if(array_key_exists("errors", $string)) {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}


        $id_array = array();


        foreach ($string['results'] as $tweets)
        {


          $id_array[] = $tweets['id_str'];


        }

      }
```

The code within callTwitter is the same as shown earlier.

To break my question down as simple as I can, I'll put it into parts:

Is there a common solution to updating php/api query parameters from Javascript on-the-fly?

**Why doesn't the `callTwitter()` do anything when I call it from Javascript, and how can I get the default API call to happen before everything else on the page loads like it did before I put it within a defined function?**

I'm not sure if it will help but I am using a file from Github to take care of the Oauth part of the API. This php file just has to be in the same folder as the script making the API call.

https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/blob/master/TwitterAPIExchange.php

### Updated `callTwitter()` function and included the js function that where I make use of the API response.

**Updated `callTwitter()`**

```
                function callTwitter(){
        $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/tweets/search/30day/dev30.json";
        $requestMethod = "GET";
        if (isset($_GET['topic']))  {$user = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/", '', $_GET['topic']);}  else {$user  = "beer+-wine";}
        //if (isset($_GET['count']) && is_numeric($_GET['count'])) {$count = $_GET['count'];} else {$count = 6;}


        $getfield = "?query=(beer+wine)";


        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
        ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
        ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
        if(array_key_exists("errors", $string)) {echo "<h3>Sorry, there was a problem.</h3><p>Twitter returned the following error message:</p><p><em>".$string[errors][0]["message"]."</em></p>";exit();}


        $id_array = array();

        //Foreach loop to create divs

        foreach ($string['results'] as $tweets)
        {


          $id_array[] = $tweets['id_str'];

        }

        return json_encode($id_array);
      }


      $ids = callTwitter();
```

**Beginning of Javascript that uses the Twitter API response stored in `$id_array` originally:**

```
    var jsarray = <?php echo $ids ?>;

          function embedTweets()
          {
            console.log("the embed tweets function has been called.")


            jsarray.forEach(function(id, i)
            {
              twttr.widgets.createTweet(
                id, document.getElementById('mycontainer'),
                {
                  conversation : 'none',    // or all
                  cards        : 'hidden',  // or visible
                  linkColor    : '#' + background_color, // default is blue
                  theme        : 'light',    // or dark
                  align        : 'center'
                }
              ).then(function(el)
              {
                readId(el);
                console.log(el);
              });
            });
```

**This implementation currently doesn't work. It appears `callTwitter` is still never being called.**

Comment: I'm probably missing something but at the end of `callTwitter` add `return $id_array;`. Then run `$ids = callTwitter();` This will give you the `$ids` on load for `jsarray`. Then in ajax do the same thing.

Comment: the way I currently have `$id_array` set to `jsarray` is: `var jsarray = <?php echo json_encode($id_array) ?>` and that works.  What I need is to be able to get a new `$id_array` from the API call after the page has loaded.

Comment: But you said it doesn't work with `function`. I'm suggesting how to use `function` to work in both cases.

Comment: I have updated with my interpretation of what  you suggested. I can't get the values in `$id_array` to `jsarray` this way - which means I can't yet test whether or not I can call `callTwitter()` with ajax.

Comment: I've tried blocking the php code into `callTwitter()` many different way and have yet to get it to work.  A lot of the php variables are initiated in another php script from github https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php that I use for authentication. Could the problem be that I have it reference in my script as `require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');` and somehow the `require_once` is causing issues?